# Unable to write SPDistributedCache call usage entry

Tags: sharepoint-server, uls, distributedcache

I'm getting this error in my LOGS quite a lot.

```
11/27/2017 09:11:03.10  w3wp.exe (0x1638)                           0x0DBC  SharePoint Foundation           General                         ajji6   High        Unable to write SPDistributedCache call usage entry.    f1c8309e-4553-10d6-299b-9b5d05fbb02b
```

29184 of them in 30 minutes.

What does this error message actually mean? What is the root cause to this error message? Is this something to be concerned about? If not, how can I stop this message appearing in my LOGS?

Answer (score 0):

For the message:Unable to write SPDistributedCache call usage entry:

Try to not use Farm account as the Distributed Cache Service account: ﻿﻿

1. Stopped the Distributed Cache Service instance via Central Admin.
2. Ran the change-user script.
3. Restarted Distributed Cache service instance
4. The identity of the AppFabric service has been updated.

For more detailed information, refer to the following aticle:

https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/jj219613.aspx

Look at the cache accounts (SuperUser and SuperReader) because of the message “unable to write SPDistributedCache call usage entry”.

For more detailed information, refer to the following article:

http://www.sharepointfire.com/MyBlog/2013/11/the-specified-user-or-domain-group-was-not-found/

Referenced from technet: https://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/lync/en-US/2be036b7-cf19-4799-881a-4422ba1a5bed/unable-to-write-spdistributedcache-call-usage-entry?forum=sharepointadmin

Comment: What is the "change-user" script in step 2 there?

Comment: By the way, I am not using the farm account as the Distributed Cache service account, so this isn't my answer. But I have seen that it is often an answer so hopefully it helps someone.

Comment: Your second link seems to be broken.

Comment: I updated the link. Script should be in the technet article... also did you check the super user accounts configuration